# Can two or more inter-related models have one common controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am a newbie in rails and I want your help. I want to build a simple project in rails that includes more than one model that are inter-related. So in this case, is it possible to create only one controller that corresponds to all the models or should I create a controller for each model? And please I want reasons for your answers. Thank you.

Comment: You can have a single `controller` for n number of models, which means any model is accessible from any controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course..

You could easily have something like:

```
#animals_controller.rb
def animals
  @dogs = Dog.all
  @cats = Cat.all
  @cheetahs = Cheetah.all
end
```

## BUT...

**Imagine having an update, edit, new, show, create and destroy for each of these models in the same controller!!**

That would be a mess - and you would end up with a complex file that would be (mildly said) annoying to maintain.

Therefore, for your own sake, and because it is good practice, you normally create a corresponding controller for each of your models(animals): model: `dog.rb`, controller: `dogs_controller.rb`, model: `cat.rb` controller: `cats_controller.rb` etc...

so you, after a few months abroad, can come back and continue your work without thinking **What the ...**.

---

I would recommend looking into the MVC (for example on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mQjtk2YDkM)) and **really** understanding how it connects the database with your view and so on.
Understand the data-flow and you will find yourself with a powerfull toll later on when you're debugging, construction forms, creating ajax-calls, custom attributes and so on.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

ous,

You need to create a controller for each model in order to have CRUD options.  It depends on what the models will do if you don't want a controller, for example if model just does some calculations and you don't really need to pass data to your view then you might not need it.